# How to ask if someone could add an example which improves the explaining of something?

Tags: translation

**Aim:** to ask someone to add an example, which improves the explaining of something

In Dutch one could say: Zou u een voorbeeld kunnen toevoegen om het antwoord te kunnen onderbouwen? Which means "Could you add an example to **...** the answer?"

Should one use **underpin**, **substantiate** or **something else** in this case?

Comment: I would like to know if substantiate is correct in this context and if that is not the case what options are possible

Comment: *Support* or *illustrate*.

Comment: It depends a good deal on whether the intent is to *challenge* your informant for some kind of *proof* of his or her claims, or merely and humbly to seek clarification of something you are perhaps a little slow to grasp. *Substantiate* or *support* is more appropriate to the former case than to the latter. *Illustrate* or *clarify* suits the latter.

Comment: Hey Utrecht - very often you just use "clarify" in some connection.  So, "give me some examples to clarify that", "could you clarify with some examples" etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know in this case you're looking to translate a specific Dutch turn of phrase, but in general, I'd say the clause at the end of the sentence isn't needed —

> Could you give an example?

On it's own, the definition of the word *example* already conveys the intention that you'd like something explained more clearly via reference to a concrete case.

Answer (score 3):

> Could you add an example to **illustrate** the answer?

Comment: If have checked the Dutch translation of this word and it answers the question. +1. Thank you.